# Is there a Javascript offchange="" function, or a way to replicate it by toggling using a class instead of value?

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

Here is my JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2tjgebgq/1/

Or the code is below:

```
<input type="text" id="fieldname" name="deselected" />   
<br>
<select multiple="multiple" onchange="updateInput(this.value)">
    <option value="selected">Volvo</option>
    <option value="selected">Saab</option>
    <option value="selected">Opel</option>
    <option value="selected">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function updateInput(deselected){
    var element = document.getElementById("fieldname").name = deselected;
    if (element == "") {
       document.getElementById("fieldname").name = "deselected";
   }
}
```

**What it does:** When anything in the select multiple is selected, the name="deselected" attribute from the text input above, toggles from "deselected" to "selected", then when nothing in the select multiple is selected, the name toggles from "deselected" to "selected".

It does this based on the VALUE="selected" attribute.

**What I need, but don't know how:** I need it to do exactly what it does now, but based on the CLASS="selected" attribute, instead of the VALUE="selected" attribute.

So the options would look like:

```
<option class="selected">Volvo</option>
```

instead of:

```
<option value="selected">Volvo</option>
```

No JQuery, only Javascript, and feel free to update the JSFiddle.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `value` field like this - each `option` is supposed to have a distinct `value` since that's the value that'll actually get submitted.   The content within the `option` tag is just for human readability, and shouldn't be parsed to determine which option was chosen.

Comment: nor should you mutate the `.name` field of the input like this.

Comment: I know, it was just an example, that is why I need to use a class, not a value, but I just can't make it work. I've been trying for 14 hours straight.

Would you have a better solution, instead of mutating the .name attribute, if I need to pass 2 POST Variables via PHP, based on the name attribute?

Comment: You have an XY problem - please explain what functionality you're actually trying to achieve (in simple words) instead of having us trying to figure out what your broken code is supposed to do.

Comment: Look at the JSFiddle, and then inspect the text field element (with Firebug or anything else), then press on the select multiple field and look at the name change, (or deselect, and look at the name change again). I just need to change it from value="" to class="" in the options, because obviously it won't work with all of the values being the same.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, and no, that's not what I asked.   What's the _intended effect of the whole thing_.    i.e. are you just trying to make a CSS style apply to the selected option(s) [ which BTW may not work on all browsers ]

Comment: Exactly how it functions in the JSFiddle, that is the intended effect: http://jsfiddle.net/2tjgebgq/1. I just need to change the value="selected" to class="selected". That's it. Inspect the text input element, then select and deselect the options, and you'll see the name change from "deselected" to "selected". I need to keep that toggle functionality as is, and just change it from using .value to .className='selected'.

Comment: no, you're still missing the point.  What's the intended _effect_, not the underlying change to the DOM.

Comment: Ok. The intended effect is when 1 or more select multiple options are selected, the name="deselected" from the input text toggles from "deslected" to "selected". Then when all of the select multiple options are deselected, the name from the input text changes from "selected" to "deselected". That is what it currently does, and is good. It relies on the values of the options, but I need it to rely on classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wish to change the class on the input (and assuming no other classes apply to it, since this trivial code will overwrite any other classes on the element):

```
function updateInput(select) {  // NB: pass the select, not its value
    document.getElementById("fieldname").className =
        select.selectedOptions.length ? "selected" : "deselected";
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/2tjgebgq/5/

Comment: The intended effect is when 1 or more select multiple options are selected, the name="deselected" from the input text toggles from "deslected" to "selected". Then when all of the select multiple options are deselected, the name from the input text changes from "selected" to "deselected". That is what it currently does, and is good. It relies on the values of the options, but I need it to rely on classes. So right now it uses updateInput(this.value) but I need it to use something like updateInput(this.className='selected');.

Comment: No, you don't.   You just need it to depend on whether an option is selected, and the DOM _gives you perfectly good ways to find that out_.  You're abusing the `class` attribute (and the `value` attribute before that) to achieve this.

Comment: It doesn't work. The class doesn't change from "selected" to "deselected" when you deselect the options (Ctrl+Click). That is the problem I face, I can't solve it.

Comment: ok, I forgot that - let me try.  OK - fixed now - I should have used `.selectedOptions` instead of `.options`

Comment: It works! Wow, thank you very much. How did you learn Javascript so well? I'm a beginner, I started learning Javascript yesterday.

Comment: The Javascript was trivial.  The hard part was figuring out what your _real_ problem was instead of being distracted by what you _thought_ your problem was.  You were getting hung up on trying to somehow pass the `class` (or `value`) from the `option` up into the `input`, when that was never the right approach to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Well, I still thank you very much. I'm only a beginner, and you solved my problem in just a few minutes.